# How to expland memory allocation transparently

Tags: c, memory

C program needs a certain amount of memory for a table. Program runs for a while then discovers it needs more memory. It can ask the OS for more memory, but that is going to come in another chunk, not contiguous with the chunk where the table is. So the table could be partitioned, but then we need an indirect access method, and sorting could be problematic. 
Or the table could be copied over to the new, larger chunk, and the original chuck freed.
Or maybe there is another method I am not aware of.
Or maybe there is a library function that would handle the whole thing?

Comment: You mean like `realloc`?

Comment: "Or the table could be copied over to the new, larger chunk, and the original chuck freed" ... What's wrong with this approach?..what's happen when realloc fails?

Comment: Yes, maybe. Never used realloc before. Sounds kind of iffy, like it only works on Tuesdays or when there's a full moon. Not something you can count on. Or is it?